# Car temperature hand going up and down but not exactly to to hott

Tags: overheating

I HAVE A 2012 Masada 6i it just started last week overheating I replace the water pump and thermostat with new ones . My temperature hand is still move up a little like it wants to go up to the H but it hadn’t but I know it still overheating  cause when I do cut car off I see a little smoke cominhg from under hood .its on rightside not the side where the water pump goes the water pump is on left . So I see just smoke coming from the other side

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It's possible that the smoke is just steam if the coolant is leaking onto the hot engine.  Are your coolant levels staying fairly steady?  Look around in the engine compartment and see if you can tell where the smoke/steam is coming from.

Comment: It’s a lil smoke coming from on right side of it

Comment: Can you tell more specifically where on the right side it's coming from?